# download Site-to-Site VPN configuration file using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to automate a site-to-site VPN connection over BGP using powershell. Is there a powershell command to get the values inside the Site-to-Site VPN configuration file. Any help would be highly appreciated

Regards,
Sajith

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below powershell cmdlet to pull the S2s VPN configuration script of a particular VPN device. We have tested in our local environment it is working fine.

```
$RG          = "<resourcegroupName>"
$GWName      = "<VPNGatewayName"
$Connection  = "<s2sConnectionName>"

# List the available VPN device models and versions
Get-AzVirtualNetworkGatewaySupportedVpnDevice -Name $GWName -ResourceGroupName $RG

# Download the configuration script for the connection
Get-AzVirtualNetworkGatewayConnectionVpnDeviceConfigScript -Name $Connection -ResourceGroupName $RG -DeviceVendor "Cisco" -DeviceFamily "ASA (Adaptive Security Appliance)" -FirmwareVersion "Cisco_ASA_[9.8+_ONLY]_RouteBased(IKEv2+VTI+BGP)"
```

For more information about How to Download VPN device configuration scripts for S2S VPN connections You can refer this  [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-download-vpndevicescript#download-the-configuration-script-using-azure-powershell).

Here is the Sample output for reference :

[image]

Comment: Hi Venkatesh,  Thx for the response. I am trying to create a local network gateway and adding the ip and bgp peer address from the config file. I am looking for an option to download the script prior establishing the connection. I m giving the input required for creating local network gateway and psk from this config file. Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: @Sajith - could you please raise a new request so that it will be helpful for other community in addressing your issue. 

If the above PowerShell cmdlets is helpful  to export the s2s configuration of particular vpn gateway ? if yes, please accept the answer.